# Building a table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple table using React and running into a small issue.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>  
  <table>
    <tbody id="content">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And then my React module:

```
var FriendsContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            data: [
                {'name':'Lorem Ipsum', 'email':'email1@gmail.com'}, 
                {'name':'Caveat Broader', 'email':'email2@gmail.com'},
                {'name':'Runther Brigsby', 'email':'email3@gmail.com'}
            ]
        }
    },

    render: function(){
        var listItems = this.state.data.map(function(person) {
            return(
                <tr>
                    <td>{person['name']}</td>
                    <td>{person['email']}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        });
        return (
            {listItems}
        )
    }
});
```

I keep getting the error `Error: FriendsContainer.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it's not a table, right? It needs to be wrapped up in a top-level element (like, say, a table).

Comment: can you give me an example? I understand what you are saying, just not sure how to do it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `map` call generates an array which you must wrap in a parent element (`tbody` in this case) as a React component has to have a single root element. You'll have to include your table header there too, and optionally the `table` tag:

```
    return (
        <table>
            <tbody id="content">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th> 
                </tr>
                {listItems}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
```

Next, alter your `map` callback so that it also accepts 'i' (index) so you can assign unique keys to your `tr`'s:

```
var listItems = this.state.data.map(function(person, i) {
        return(
            <tr key={i}>
                <td>{person['name']}</td>
                <td>{person['email']}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    });
```

This should do it.

Comment: what should I set the return value for the render function?

Comment: you can see the return value in the 1st code snippet, it's a React element called <table>

Answer (score 0):

you should be atleast wrap in a div like

```
return (
            <div>{listItems}</div>
        )
```

and as @Dave Newton said there should be a higher level tag like `table` instead of `div`.As per  error the render method should return null or empty `<div>` not anything else.

Comment: (Well, technically you can't wedge a `<div>` into a table like that; it'd be invalid HTML.)

Comment: I am not talking about just `div` in your case it is `table` tag.It will accept only html node or null

Comment: (So maybe update the answer to be relevant to the OP's question? I mean, you explicitly state you could wrap it in a div, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: yea, thats the part I'm confused about. How should I wrap it so it fits in with the table? What should the HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message it says, `...You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object....`, that's right, the return type of render is `JSX.Element` as,

```
---
render(): JSX.Element {
retrun <JSX.Element>{Something}
}
```

*Something*: for you question it should be `table`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>React Tutorial</title>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

React components:

```
var BuildTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            columns: ['name', 'email', 'test'],
            rows: [
                {'name':'brandev balbusor', 'email':'email1@gmail.com'},
                {'name': 'lorem ipsum', 'email':'email2@gmail.com'},
                {'name':'titus maldav', 'email':'email3#gmail.com'}
            ]
        }
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <table>
                <CreateColumns col={this.state.columns} />
                <CreateRows people={this.state.rows} />
            </table>
        )   
    }
});

var CreateColumns = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var columns = this.props.col.map(function(column){
            return <th> {column} </th>
        });

        return (
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {columns}
                </tr>
            </thead>
        )
    }
});

var CreateRows = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var data = this.props.people.map(function(person){
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{person['name']}</td>
                    <td>{person['email']}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        });
        return (
            <tbody>
                {data}
            </tbody>
        )
    }
});
```